# Open two xml documents for lookups using xsl.both have same element

Tags: xml, xslt, lookup

I'm using xsl for a XML transformation and I have to use multiple lookups for that. Lookup xml's have following format.

```
<lookups>
    <lookup attr1="val1a" attr2="val1b">
    <lookup attr1="val2a" attr2="val2b">
<lookups>
```

All lookup xmls use above format. for example lookup file for element A is there and another lookup file for element B is also there with same element structure but different values which are relevant to element B. Then I'm doing my lookups in main xsl file as follows.

```
<!-- here come the first lookup for element A -->
<xsl:key name="A-lookup" match="lookup" use="@attr1"/>
<xsl:variable name="ALookupDoc" select="document('ALookup.xml')"/>

<xsl:template match="A">
    <Anew>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$ALookupDoc/*">
        <xsl:with-param name="curr-code" select="string(.)"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    </Anew>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="lookups">
    <xsl:param name="curr-code"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="key('A-lookup', $curr-code)/@attr2"/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- And the second one for element B -->
<xsl:key name="B-lookup" match="lookup" use="@attr1"/>
<xsl:variable name="BLookupDoc" select="document('BLookup.xml')"/>

<xsl:template match="B">
    <Anew>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$BLookupDoc/*">
        <xsl:with-param name="curr-code" select="string(.)"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    </Anew>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="lookups">
    <xsl:param name="curr-code"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="key('B-lookup', $curr-code)/@attr2"/>
</xsl:template>
```

OK now. the problem is first lookup which is for the element A works fine. But not the second one. As I see there are two problematic parts.

1. Both lookups have same element names(lookups and lookup). Once I change second lookup XML to differnt elements(lookupsX and lookupX) and templates accordingly they work fine.
2. There are two templates for same element(lookups for element A and B)

Still I'm not sure exactly where the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you have two templates with exactly the same `match` value, so only one of them is actually being used.  You could resolve this by giving them different modes, but how about something like this:

```
  <!-- here come the first lookup for element A -->
  <xsl:key name="A-lookup" match="lookup" use="@attr1"/>
  <xsl:variable name="ALookupDoc" select="document('ALookup.xml')"/>

  <xsl:template match="A">
    <Anew>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$ALookupDoc/*">
        <xsl:with-param name="curr-code" select="string(.)"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="keyName" select="'A-lookup'" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </Anew>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- And the second one for element B -->
  <xsl:key name="B-lookup" match="lookup" use="@attr1"/>
  <xsl:variable name="BLookupDoc" select="document('BLookup.xml')"/>

  <xsl:template match="B">
    <Anew>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$BLookupDoc/*">
        <xsl:with-param name="curr-code" select="string(.)"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="keyName" select="'B-lookup'" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </Anew>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="lookups">
    <xsl:param name="curr-code"/>
    <xsl:param name="keyName" />

    <xsl:value-of select="key($keyName, $curr-code)/@attr2"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

Then again, you might not need two keys, since they both have the same definition. Please see if this works:

```
  <!-- here come the first lookup for element A -->
  <xsl:key name="lookup" match="lookup" use="@attr1"/>
  <xsl:variable name="ALookupDoc" select="document('ALookup.xml')"/>

  <xsl:template match="A">
    <Anew>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$ALookupDoc/*">
        <xsl:with-param name="curr-code" select="string(.)"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </Anew>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- And the second one for element B -->
  <xsl:variable name="BLookupDoc" select="document('BLookup.xml')"/>

  <xsl:template match="B">
    <Anew>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$BLookupDoc/*">
        <xsl:with-param name="curr-code" select="string(.)"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </Anew>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="lookups">
    <xsl:param name="curr-code"/>

    <xsl:value-of select="key('lookup', $curr-code)/@attr2"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: vola! it does the trick.

yes actually it looks like two templates with same match was the problem.

Thanks JLRishe

Comment: @susithasenarath Glad to help.  After some further thought, I'm not so sure that you need separate keys here.  Please give my more succinct answer above a try.

Comment: Yes. Until attributes of lookup elements for same your second thought was better. If they are different(In my actual case it is) I can use the first method. 

Earlier I was trying to comeup with a solution using call-template to distinguish two looup templates.This way is fine. :) 
Thank you for your quick reply.